# Java Benchmarking: Ensuring that objects are not reused after coming out of scope

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, arraylist, garbage-collection

I am benchmarking several algorithms that do a variation of k-th closest neighbor problem.
I'm seeing troubling results when repeatedly running algorithms that sort my data.

### Update

It seems like the data itself is not being cached, as people have said. I ran the same n = 50000 test, but generated random points in both ArrayLists every time I ran three tests. The speedup that I was wary of still occurred. This DOES seem to be the JITC feature.

Output:

```
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 21716
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 24014
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 17655

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 22034
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 23975
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 18438

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 20097
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15677
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14399

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 20457
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15141
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14146

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 20143
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15834
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14084

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 20173
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15170
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 13745

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 19625
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 14924
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 15972

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 19388
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15209
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 13639

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 19420
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 14779
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 13798

Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 19390
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15078
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 13548
```

### Original Query

Background/Details:

I have two unsorted n-sized ArrayLists of Points- A and B. For every Point P in A, check to see how many Points in B are within a distance d from P.

Algorithms:

- Brute Force
- - For every Point P1 in A, check every Point P2 in B.
- Sorted Smart Brute Force
- - Create a temporary ArrayList C, and deep copy B into it.
- - Sort C by x-value of the Points.
- - Scan B until reaching the first P2.x that exceeds (P1.x + d)
- QuickSelect
- - Create a temporary ArrayList C, and deep copy B into it.
- - Sort C by x-value of the Points.
- - For every Point P1 in A, do a binary search through C, until a Point P2 is found whose x value is within P1.x ± d.
- - Scan left and right from the found Point. Stop scanning when reaching a Point that lies outside of the d range.

Sample:

```
public void quickSelect(ArrayList<Point> field1, ArrayList<Point> input2, int distance){
    ArrayList<Point> field2 = new ArrayList<Point>();

    deepCopy(field2, input2);

    startTimer("Starting :: Quickselect.\n");
    Collections.sort(field2, new ComparePoints());

    for(int i = 0; i < field1.size(); ++i){
        //Find pivot
        ...
        //Scan to its left until out of bounds.
        ...
        //Scan to its right until out of bounds.
        ...
    }

    endTimer("Stopping :: Quickselect. ");

    field2.clear();
}
```

where deepCopy is:

```
private void deepCopy(ArrayList<Point> field1, ArrayList<Point> input1){
    for(int i = 0; i < input1.size(); ++i){
        field1.add(input1.get(i).getLocation());
    }
}
```

Testing method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int points = 50000;
    ArrayList<Point> field1 = generator.makeGraph(points);
    ArrayList<Point> field2 = generator.makeGraph(points);
    GraphTester tester = new GraphTester(field1);
    int maxDistance = 300;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        tester.bruteForce(field1, field2, maxDistance);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        tester.sortedBruteForce(field1, field2, maxDistance);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        tester.quickSelect(field1, field2, maxDistance);
    }
}
```

The results:

```
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 22851
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 22482
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 20690
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 21073
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 20860
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 21311
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 20847
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 21000
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 20503
Stopping :: Brute Force. Time (ms): 21342

Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 23083
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 22616
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15881
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15323
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15930
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15360
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 16072
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15601
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 16952
Stopping :: Sorted 'Smart' Brute Force. Time (ms): 15950

Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 18202
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 18109
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14685
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14401
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14052
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14782
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14175
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14187
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 13870
Stopping :: Quickselect. Time (ms): 14601
```

As you can see, the Sorted Smart Brute Force and Quickselect algorithms start off with a high computation time, but level off to a much better number as the tests are repeated.

Though I'm clearing the temporary ArrayList, I feel like the sorted ArrayList is SOMEHOW being retained by the JVM and reused/remapped to the new ArrayList pointers.

My question is two-fold, then:

- Does this seem like a case of caching?
- Can I guarantee that the data is not cached?
- - If I randomize the Points every time I generate the graphs, I'm betting there would be more control, but then I couldn't be sure that the algorithms are fairly matched.

Comment: Seems to me that this is more the JITC at work than caching, although what exactly it is doing/optimizing, I'm not sure. Honestly, I'm not sure caching in the way you speak of is possible in general, as that optimization might be be extremely difficult to prove and not useful in too many situations (that I can think of, at least)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see why you're **deep**-cloning the data.

> Does this seem like a case of caching?

No, it's the JITC getting better on what you're running. Each non-trivial Java benchmark needs a warmup, during which statistics get gathered and then the relevant part of code (the `HotSpot`) gets compiled and optimized heavily.

A more complex algorithm need more warmup.

> Can I guarantee that the data is not cached?

I can't see any caching there. Who would do it? The JITC can't understand what you're doing. If it knew you're computing the same thing all the time, all the times but one would be zero.

> If I randomize the Points every time I generate the graphs, I'm betting there would be more control, but then I couldn't be sure that the algorithms are fairly matched.

Go for it if you feel like this. I guess you can rather trust your benchmark without doing it.

## Update after the comment

**Warmup:** The common situation is a server running for many hours (at least) doing mostly the same operations all the time. For such a server measuring the performance during the first minutes would make little sense. Another situation needed a warmup is measuring or optimizing very fast operations like e.g. String.hashCode, which are typically repeated many thousands times. You situation with a single long-taking computation seems to be an exception.

Still, what I wrote about the warmup is a plausible *explanation* for your observations. Anyway, `Quickselect` was the winner in all runs, so the choice is clear. The fact that it improved later is nice bonus for the winner. The next places are less clear, but 22851 vs 23083 is no real win, as the measurement error is bigger (and so might be the cost for the deep-copy). Re-run you benchmark several times (with a fresh JVM) if you want to know more (1 iteration should suffice).

Comment: I clone the data to make sure that I'm not sorting a sorted ArrayList. In a real-world situation, I can't assume that my data structure is sorted.

As a follow up to your comment on each benchmark needing warmup, how does that make for a good real test? In a real-world case, if you're running an algorithm like this once, then my data seems to indicate that the brute force method is better than the smart brute force. If, however, I'm doing the algorithm many times, brute force becomes less favored.